# Конвертировать Calendar в Date

Tags: android, дата, calendar

Пытаюсь конвертировать Calendar в Date, но получаю погрешность примерно в 41 секунду.

```
remindDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Использую AlarmManager в Android:

```
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, remindDate.getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

Как исправить погрешность? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Если теструете на KITKAT и новее, то похоже, что эту 41 секунду Ваше устройство пропустило для экономии энергии.
Попробуйте `AlarmManager.setExact()` в этом случае.

Comment: Огрешность осталась. Может быть я не правильно конвертировал Calendar в Date?

Comment: Пишите в лог remindDate и станет ясно, где проблема. Возможно оно где-то модифицируется.